# Flutter app is stuck on white screen after building release

Tags: android, ios, flutter

After building the app in release into my iPhone 7, this is the screen I'm seeing:
[image]

This is how it should look like:
[image]

This is the same in both Android and iOS in release mode. When I run the apps on emulators (debug mode) the app works fine. The app uses HTTPS requests to work, might that be the problem?

My Info.plist file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>View MET</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml file inside /main:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.emirs.view_met">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application
        android:label="View MET"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My Flutter version:

```
Flutter 2.3.0-13.0.pre.145 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fdb1fb184d (9 hours ago) • 2021-05-24 22:04:02 -0700
Engine • revision b1385c0df1
Tools • Dart 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-145.0.dev)
```

My home.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:view_met/search.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'about.dart';
import 'all.dart';
import 'detailsArt.dart';
import 'favorites.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
  }

  checkEmpty() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var list = prefs.getStringList("favorites");

    if (list == null) {
      prefs.setStringList("favorites", []);
    }
  }


  fetchData(String id) async {
    var request = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/$id"));

    return request.body;
  }

  _writeData(String id) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var list = prefs.getStringList("favorites");

    if (list!.contains(id)) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text("This item is already in your favorites!"),
          )
      );
    }
    else {
      list.add(id);

      prefs.setStringList("favorites", list);

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text("Added to your favorites list"),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Undo',
              onPressed: () {
                _deleteData(id);
              },
            ),
          )
      );
    }
  }

  _deleteData(String id) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var list = prefs.getStringList("favorites");

    list!.remove(id);

    prefs.setStringList("favorites", list);

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Removed from your favorites list"),
          action: SnackBarAction(
            label: 'Undo',
            onPressed: () {
              _writeData(id);
            },
          ),
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    checkEmpty();

    welcomeText() {
      var now = DateTime.now();

      if (now.hour <= 11 && now.hour >= 5) {
        return Text("Good Morning", style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplaySc(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
      }
      else if (now.hour <= 17 && now.hour >= 12) {
        return Text("Good Afternoon", style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplaySc(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
      }
      else if (now.hour <= 21 && now.hour >= 18 && now.hour >= 19 && now.hour >= 5 || now.hour == 0) {
        return Text("Good Evening", style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplaySc(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
      }
      else {
        return Text("Hello", style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplaySc(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
      }
    }

    var randint1 = Random().nextInt(70000);
    var randint2 = Random().nextInt(70000);
    var randint3 = Random().nextInt(70000);
    var randint4 = Random().nextInt(70000);
    var randint5 = Random().nextInt(70000);
    var randint6 = Random().nextInt(70000);


    builder(String id) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchData(id),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          var data = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toString());

          var leading;
          var artist;

          try {
            if (data["primaryImageSmall"] == "") {
              leading = Icon(Icons.dangerous, color: Colors.red);
            }
            else {
              leading = Image.network(data["primaryImageSmall"]);
            }

            if (data["artistDisplayName"]== "") {
              artist = "Unknown";
            }
            else {
              artist = data["artistDisplayName"];
            }
          }
          on TypeError {
            return SizedBox.shrink();
          }

          return Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  leading: leading,
                  title: Text(data["title"]),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    "by $artist",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailsPage(id: data["objectID"].toString())),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text("Details", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _writeData(data["objectID"].toString());
                      },
                      child: Text("Add to Favorites", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }

    var _controller = TextEditingController();


    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 400,
                  child: Positioned.fill(
                    child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/MET.jpg",
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(117, 117, 117, 0.5),
                        colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 20),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 30,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.info),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutPage()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 40, 20),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: IconButton(
                        iconSize: 30,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FavoritesPage()),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50,80, 20),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: IconButton(
                        iconSize: 30,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh_outlined),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) => this.widget)
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 150, 0, 20),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Text(
                      'View MET',
                      style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplaySc(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  )
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 200, 0, 20),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: welcomeText(),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 280, 0, 20),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 300,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _controller,
                        onSubmitted: (String value) {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) => SearchPage(text: _controller.text)
                              )
                          );
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(99),
                              ),
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            hintText: "Search View MET",
                            fillColor: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Random Items You Could Like", style: GoogleFonts.merriweather(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black)),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 443,
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            builder(randint1.toString()),
                            builder(randint2.toString()),
                            builder(randint3.toString()),
                            builder(randint4.toString()),
                            builder(randint5.toString()),
                            builder(randint6.toString()),
                            TextButton(
                             onPressed: () {
                               Navigator.push(
                                   context,
                                   MaterialPageRoute(
                                       builder: (BuildContext context) => AllPage()
                                   )
                               );
                             },
                             child: Text("See more"),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am thinking that the HTTPS request is the thing that freezes the app. I checked some other questions but none of them really worked.

Comment: Post the code of the first screen that you are showing.

Comment: @DarShan I updated the question. If you need to see more files, you can check [this](https://github.com/MakufonSkifto/view_met/blob/master/lib/) GitHub repo.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling methods inside the `build` method, move the tasks to `initState()` properly.

Comment: @DarShan Thank you for your advise but that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Is there any stacktrace available? Try installing with XCode in Release Mode (Keep Debuggable checked in the Edit Scheme) & see if there is any stacktrace logged or not.

Comment: @DarShan It doesn't look like there is any stacktraces but there is something in the logs: https://hastebin.com/gucotadile.apache. This doesn't crash or freeze the emulator though.

Comment: The info. suggests there something wrong with your widget tree (`type 'ParentData' is not a subtype of type 'StackParentData' in type cast`), as I said move method calls & variable initialisation to `initState`, the build should only be used to create a Widget Tree.

Comment: @DarShan Is the freeze caused by the errors Flutter is raising? I removed all of the functions inside build() and the problem is still there.